# SPLUNK - Field extraction not performed for JSON uploaded through EC endpoint

Tags: json, endpoint, extract, splunk

We have add-on that submits data successfully REST API endpoint but we want to switch to use EC endpoint.
However upon testing, we discovered that field extraction is not performed when we submit JSON data through the EC endpoint although the same sourcetype is used.
I use Splunk 6.4.1

I have screenshots of how the JSON fields can be extracted correctly if I upload the data manually & how the fields have NOT been extracted if the JSON file is sent through EC endpoint

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3ujiBaFxN0ZenAtVGtid29JY3M

The properties of my source type follows

```
pulldown_type = true
INDEXED_EXTRACTIONS = json
KV_MODE = none
NO_BINARY_CHECK = true
TIMESTAMP_FIELDS = TIMESTAMP
TZ = UTC
category = Structured
description = Test
disabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON field extraction is not supported in HEC *yet* but it is coming very soon.

In the meanwhile one option is to use a variant of the approach I blogged on here: http://blogs.splunk.com/2016/06/28/eureka-extracting-key-value-pairs-from-json-fields/ which relies on regex extractions